# Rails 5.2 - how to associate a Report model with two Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a threaded discussion context, I want to allow Users to report offensive Comments. I have a Reports table in which I want to record both the User who wrote the Comment and the User who made the complaint.

My Reports table is currently as follows:

```
create_table "reports", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "comment_id"
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.integer "author_id"
  t.text "body"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["comment_id"], name: "index_reports_on_comment_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reports_on_user_id"
end
```

`user_id` records the id the user making the complaint. `author_id` records the id of the author of the comment.

The associations are set up as follows:

**report.rb**

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'author_id'
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Nothing yet, but presumably need something
end
```

In the console, I can query as follows:

```
r = Report.last
=> #<Report id: ...
r.user
=> #<User id: ...
```

but I can't query

```
r.author
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `author' for #<Report:0x000000082ef588>
```

So the first question is how can I enable this type of query.

Secondly, I'd like to be able to query the complaints (Reports) made against particular Users, so:

```
u = User.last
=> #<User id: ...
u.complaints
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [...
```

What do I need to add to enable these queries too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'author_id'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Nothing yet, but presumably need something
  has_many :reports #user reports
  #Query the complaints (Reports) made against particular Users
  has_many :complaints, class_name: 'Report', foreign_key: 'author_id'
end
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I read through the docs but didn't find them particularly clear. Is there any reference you can recommend?